Install Ubuntu on a surface pro 4 - /init: line 49: can't open /dev/sda: no medium found
I try to install Ubuntu on a Microsoft Surface Pro 4 with Windows already installed.
I have a big part of the disk that is not used (free space).
When I start on my USB stick, I get the initial screen, where I can choose to try/install Ubuntu.
And then there is this error message on the CLI:
/init: line 49: can't open /dev/sda: no medium found

I've tried to reinstall the USB stick with different devices and ISO, different OS... But always the same message.
Before wiping this Surface Pro, I would know if there is another solution.
Thanks for your help.
